# How to Check if a Value in a Column is Present in the Following Row?

Tags: python, pandas, indexing, dataframe

I have the following dataframe that I want to do some manipulation over it:

```
   AutoStudyID   DiagDate  DiagName
0           34 2010-09-23      Lung
1           34 2001-01-01      Skin
2           48 2008-01-01     Brain
```

How can I use the power of pandas to check for the case where an `AutoStudyID` is followed directly by the same `AutoStudyID` in the next row?

For example like the following two rows:

```
0           34 2010-09-23      Lung
1           34 2001-01-01      Skin
```

My ultimate goal is to make the dataframe has only one unique AutoStudyID per row. And the data of the delicate AutoStudyID should be merged into the one unique by creating new columns, the output should be something like this:

```
   AutoStudyID   DiagDate  DiagName    DiagDate2    DiageName2
0           34 2010-09-23      Lung   2001-01-01          Skin
1           48 2008-01-01     Brain
```

Any idea how to tackle this problem?

Comment: Please, improve the question's redaction and explain well that you want.

Answer (score 1):

the following will check whether the value in the next row (for numeric and datetime dtypes) is the same?

```
In [203]: df.AutoStudyID.diff() == 0
Out[203]:
0    False
1     True
2    False
Name: AutoStudyID, dtype: bool

In [204]: df[df.AutoStudyID.diff() == 0]
Out[204]:
   AutoStudyID    DiagDate DiagName
1           34  2001-01-01     Skin
```

or a bit more generic way (it'll work also for `strings`):

```
In [206]: df.AutoStudyID.shift() == df.AutoStudyID
Out[206]:
0    False
1     True
2    False
Name: AutoStudyID, dtype: bool
```

Comment: My ultimate goal is to make the dataframe has only one unique `AutoStudyID` per row.  And the data of the delicate `AutoStudyID` should be merged into the one unique by creating new columns such as `DiagName2` and `DiagDate2`

Comment: @MEhsan, then check [drop_duplicated()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html) method

Comment: This solution gives True when the previous is the same. OP is asking for the next. "followed directly by..."

Comment: But how could I merge the data if I have drop the duplicate rows?  @MaxU

Comment: consider using `groupby`

Answer (score 1):

Try adding a new column with the following AutoStudyID:

```
df['next'] = df.AutoStudyID.shift(-1)
df

    AutoStudyID DiagDate    DiagName    next
0   34          2010-09-23  Lung        34
1   34          2001-01-01  Skin        48
2   48          2008-01-01  Brain       NaN
```

Each row will have the next's id also. The rows should be sorted by AutoStudyID.

You can also try to group by AutoStudyID:

```
df.groupby('AutoStudyID')
```

For Example:

```
for group in df.groupby('AutoStudyID'):
    print(group)
```

You get these groups, you can do what you need:

```
('34',   AutoStudyID    DiagDate DiagName next
0          34  2010-09-23     Lung   34
1          34  2001-01-01     Skin   48)
('48',   AutoStudyID    DiagDate DiagName next
2          48  2008-01-01    Brain  NaN)
```

Answer (score 0):

Iterate over the rows with `iterrows()` and compare the field AutoStudyID with the last value found.

```
last = None
for i, row in df.iterrows():
    if last == df['AutoStudyID'][i]:
        print('I found it in position: %s' % i)
    else:
        last = df['AutoStudyID'][i]
```